# Who are the real big share holders of $AMDA?

Tags: stocks, shares

Amedica is a listed company on NASDAQ.

According to Google Finance, it's currently valued at 19.05M. And the Inst. own is **16%**.

According to the latest [file](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1269026/000149315216008810/def14a.htm) they submitted to SEC, the executive team got only `67,145` shares, which is `0.6%` of the total piece.

Then who are the real big shareholders of this company?

Comment: Try looking up the 13G?

Comment: @NuWin how to? Is there any links?

Comment: Try using the Edgar system

Answer (score 2):

There are not necessarily large shareholders, maybe every other Joe Schmoe owns 3 or 5 shares; and many shares might be inside investment funds.

If you are looking for *voting rights*, typically, the banks/investment companies that host the accounts of the individual shareholders/fund owners have the collective voting rights, so the Fidelity's and Vanguard's of the world will be the main and deciding voters. That is very common.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any famous cases that a company run well while its shares are very separated owned?